# Error when npm run start-dev

Tags: json, reactjs, npm, webpack

I've error when running file. The command is `npm run start-dev`. I need your help. thanks!

screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GV8v.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5guH.png

Answer (score 0):

Those are warnings not errors, you should be ok to ignore them. Please post the output into the question rather than screen capturing the terminal.